# How to make WMI call from node.js on Linux?

Tags: c#, node.js, mono, coreclr, edgejs

I'm looking for a way to make nodejs "native" WMI calls to remote Microsoft Windows Servers from Linux running on Linux.

All modules which I have found on npm are just wrappers for binary executables (mostly wmic) and this is not a solution which I'm looking for, as I would like for this process to be more efficient without requirement to create a new system process.

Tried to use great module called edge from tjanczuk (https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) however in order to make a WMI call in C# a ManagementObjectSearcher() from System.Management.dll is needed. Proof of concept works great when run on MS Windows however is missing System.Management.dll when executed on Linux.

Linux has Mono and newly released by Microsoft CoreCLR for Linux. First has System.Management.dll and event ManagementObjectSearcher() but not working as source code comment explains "TODO" :( On the other hand I wasn't able to find ManagementObjectSearcher() in CoreCLR.

Any other ways to make native nodejs WMI calls from Linux to remote MS Windows Server without use for wrappers which execute a binary ?